# What is the Build Version of SharePoint Server 2016 RC?

Tags: 2016, build-version

Upgrading SharePoint Server Beta 2 to Release Candidate using the guide [Install a software update for SharePoint Server 2016 Release Candidate](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806338(v=office.16).aspx), I'm still confused if I got the correct build version.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I was under the impression that the Config_DB would have 16.0.4336.1000 and not 16.0.4327.1000 it is now. But I may be wrong.

**What is the Build Version of SharePoint Server 2016 RC?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4327 is correct if LPs are not deployed, as your scenario outlines.

Comment: If I install another Lamguage Pack than English, will the build version change?

Comment: I believe it should, but that said you're running the correct build. Not something to be concerned with, not all patches for SharePoint (from 2010 on up through 2016) will increment the build number.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that version 4327 is the version I see also without the language packs.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could find build version along with KB's on https://sathiya.io/sharepoint-2016-builds

Comment: you can add brief details from the link.